# Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty Compiler: Syntax error in template (Prestashop)

Tags: smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, dashboard

my back office (dashboard/administrator) wouldn't show anything but a blank white page.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty Compiler: Syntax error in template "/home/kanziaho/public_html/admkanzi/themes/default/template/helpers/form/form.tpl" on line 25 "" illegal recursive call of "" <-- thrown in /home/kanziaho/public_html/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 25
```

I've tried to upload newer "fresh" versions of prestashop but is nothing worked.
And I uploaded my backup data after that but still only can see the message (Fetal Error)

My back office wouldn't show anything so I can't do anything now. 
What should I do. If you can I would like to let you know my site account information.

Please help me.

Comment: My prestashop ver is 1.6.1.4 and I am using leothem

Comment: Have you compared the `form.tpl` file against the one you may have in your backups? Could you reproduce the first 50 lines or so of that file in your question?

Comment: Yes I did, and now I have fixed it but there are other errors

Comment: Maybe you can ask another question.